# Two binary attributes to be output in one column 

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a single table with a list of `bit` datatypes. If two of these attributes, we'll call them `attrib1` and `attrib2` are BOTH = 1, I would like for a single column in the query to be output as 1.

If BOTH of them are 0, I would like to union the first result set to the second one, where if both of the attributes are 0, a single column would be output with a 0

so

```
SELECT attrib1, attrib2  
FROM myTable
WHERE (attrib1 = 1) AND (attrib2 = 1)
```

I need that statement to output in one column with a '1' ONLY if cases are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Bitwise Exclusive OR (^)` in the *WHERE* clause so that only rows in which both the columns `attrib1` or `attrib2` have either *0* or *1* are selected. In the `SELECT`, you need to use the `Bitwise And (&)` to display *1* if both columns have **1** or display *0* if both columns have **0**.

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.myTable
(
        id      int NOT NULL IDENTITY
    ,   attrib1 bit NOT NULL
    ,   attrib2 bit NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.myTable (attrib1, attrib2) VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (0, 1),
    (1, 0),
    (0, 0);

SELECT  id
    ,   attrib1 & attrib2 AS attrib1_2
FROM    dbo.myTable
WHERE   (attrib1 ^ attrib2 = 0);
```

Result would be:

```
id   attrib1_2
--   ---------
1       1
4       0
```

Comment: So an ID is also included in this yet, and instead of the query results returning ID attribute1 attribute2 where attribute1 and attribute 2 only have '1s' I would like an alias column of, say attrib1_2.  I plan on unioning that result with those that are both 0s